# PersistenceProvider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence not found

Tags: hibernate, ejb, jboss7.x

I am getting the following Exception while deploying my EJB EAR into `JBoss7.1` server:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider '
            org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        ' not found
```

I have the following jar added with my EJB(These are also resides inside my jboss modules `jboss_home/modules/org/hibernate/main`):

```
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-infinispan-4.0.1.Final.jar
```

Here is how I added hibernate provider at my `persistence.xml` file:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="hbPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>
            org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        </provider>
        ...
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: What about other libs? Have you added javaassist and spring-orm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it...
create a java class HibernateUtil.java and provide the persistence unit name to entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    static {
                try {
                     entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hbPU");  // here is your persistence unit name
                     System.out.println("Entity Menager Test.............."+ entityManagerFactory);
                } catch (Throwable ex) {

                    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);

                  }
    }

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
         return entityManagerFactory;
    }

}
```

and Create your persistence.xml like this

```
<persistence version="2.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="hbPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <!-- map your classes. -->
    <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="xxx" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"value="xxx"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxx" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Your Error will not come...

Comment: `<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>` needs to be in one line. I placed it in three lines and hence it didn't work for me. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error. All I had to to was to put the provider argument into 1 line

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

It was

```
<provider>
  org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
</provider>
```